# Checkall and uncheckall on single button is not worked for single checkbox. Please give me solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Checkall and uncheckall on single button is worked if there is more than one checkbox present.But it will not worked for single checkbox. Please give me solution that will worked for both if single checkbox present or multiple checkbox present in javascript.

Here is my code

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-theme02 btn-xs " id="checkbtn" name="checkbtn" value="CheckAll" onClick="Check(document.myform.checklist1)"/>
<input  type="checkbox" style="width: 20px" class="checkbox form-control centered" id="checklist1" name="checklist1" value="<%=voucher.getId()%>"/>


<script>
function Check(chk)
            {
                if(document.myform.checkbtn.value=="CheckAll"){
                    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                        chk[i].checked = true ;
                    document.myform.checkbtn.value="UnCheckAll";
                }else{

                    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                        chk[i].checked = false ;
                    document.myform.checkbtn.value="CheckAll";
                }
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code and create a jsfiddle exampple for the same...
here is the code :-

```
function Check() {
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("checklist1");
    var button = document.getElementsByName("checkbtn")[0];
    if (button.value == "CheckAll") {
        for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++)
            checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
        button.value = "UnCheckAll";
    } else {

        for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++)
            checkBoxes[i].checked = false;
        button.value = "CheckAll";
    }
}
```

working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/19/

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```js
function Check()
            {
                var chk=document.getElementsByName("checklist1");
                if(document.getElementById("checkbtn").value=="CheckAll"){
                    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                        chk[i].checked = true ;
                    document.getElementById("checkbtn").value="UnCheckAll";
                }else{

                    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                        chk[i].checked = false ;
                    document.getElementById("checkbtn").value="CheckAll";
                }
            }
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn btn-theme02 btn-xs " id="checkbtn" name="checkbtn" value="CheckAll" onClick="Check()"/>
<input  type="checkbox" style="width: 20px" class="checkbox form-control centered" id="checklist1" name="checklist1" value="<%=voucher.getId()%>"/>
```